# Accounts attacked

Tags: centos, security

I have run two commands below. I find some of the accounts attack as below. I do not have the account test,teste,oracle and admin in my home directory. As there system account. How to know which are valid and in-valid accounts.

```
lastb | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -5
   5898 root
    196 test
    164 oracle
    154 teste
     86 admin
[root@localhost ~]# awk 'gsub(".*sshd.*Failed password for (invalid user )?", "") {print $1}' /var/log/secure* | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -5
  13835 root
    386 test
    185 oracle
    146 admin
    131 nagios
```

Comment: You may want to install [fail2ban](http://centoshelp.org/security/fail2ban/) on that server -- it'll automatically and temporarily block any IP adress that repeatedly attempts to log in with invalid credentials.

Comment: @jordanm which is the right method to install fail2ban because I try before with yum it does not work. Beside fail2ban will ossec be a good tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are just automated bot attacks and not unusual for any internet exposed system. To get a list of users you can use `getent` in CentOS:

```
getent passwd | awk -F':' '{ print $1 }'
```

To put it together with what you already have:

```
while read -r count user; do
   printf '%s %s ' "$user" "$count" 
   if getent passwd | grep -q "^$user:"; then
       printf 'valid\n'
   else
       printf 'invalid\n'
   fi
done < <(awk 'gsub(".*sshd.*Failed password for (invalid user )?", "") {print $1}' /var/log/secure* | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -5)
```

Comment: @ChandraRavoori "unusual", thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: I got this results
root 13835 valid
test 386 invalid
oracle 185 invalid
admin 146 invalid
nagios 131 invalid so mean those invalid are being tried is it? They did not manage to break in the system I guess rite?